# How to save PDF file on Sdcard created using iText?

Tags: android, itext

I am using iText library to create a pdf file from given string. But how can i save this document file to external storage ?

```
        Document document = new Document();
        fileName = "Hello" + ".pdf";
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hellooo"));
        document.close();
```

What should i do after it to save this document to external storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `fileName` point to a location on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), rather than be `"Hello" + ".pdf"`.

You can access your own app's specific spot on external storage via `getExternalFilesDir()`, called on your `Activity` or other `Context`. Or, you could consider storing the file in a common location, such as those available from `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`.

Most likely, you will need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, by having a `<uses-permission>` element for it in the right spot in your manifest. If your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, and you are using `getExternalFilesDir()`, you will not need this permission.